# Jenkins pipeline script error unexpected token: }

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have a simple pipeline job, following Jenkins documentation example https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/, in the section 'Example 2. Stage-level Agent Section'. For the life of me I cannot figure out why I am getting this error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 7: unexpected token: } @ line 7, column 13.
               }
               ^
1 error
```

I have retyped, went through line by line to check for characters and pasted into editor to see if I could see what the issue is. Here is my snippet:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'test-deploy01' }
    stages {
        stage ('Change Directory') {
            steps {
                cd /var/jenkins_home/p4/tools/ansible/DL/app/scripts/
            }
        }
        stage ('Blaze Healthcheck') {
            steps {
                PYTHONPATH=shared python app_service_check.py -y 2023 -e test -p pc
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should that line with `cd` be `sh 'cd /var/....'` ?

Comment: You are right, wrapping command in 'sh' made the error go away....save you from an essay, long story short I originally had the commands wrapped in 'sh' or 'script' but that opened a different shell and I could not view output in console. I guess I was using sh wrong as the output in console and stage view show now. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you're missing the section between stage and steps that specifies the agent. Where the complete Pipeline is installed is specified in the agent section. Stage-level usage is not required, but the section must be defined at the pipeline block's top level.

```
  `stage('Example Build') {
        agent { docker 'maven:3.9.0-eclipse-temurin-11' } 
        steps {
            echo 'Hello, Maven'
            sh 'mvn --version'
        }
    }`
```

If that does not resolve your problem, please refer to this  [YAML Pipeline Tutorial](https://www.letsdevops.net/post/letsdevops-complete-guide-to-learn-and-setup-yaml-pipeline-in-azure-devops).

Comment: the 'sh' part works, thanks for the link Ill check it out later. :)